# Ubuntu 20.04 Server remove local gateway from DNS Server

Tags: server, dns, netplan

Here is my setup :

```
 network:
 version: 2
 renderer: NetworkManager
 #renderer: networkd
 ethernets:
  enp2s0:
   dhcp4: yes
   addresses: []
   nameservers:
           addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
  enx28ee52061e61:
   dhcp4: yes
   addresses: []
```

systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2

```
DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1
                  1.1.1.1
                  1.0.0.1
```

So every domain is resolved from 192.168.1.1 (router-gateway IP).

How can i remove it and all domains resolved from "1.1.1.1"?

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver fe80::1%2
search home
```

cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

```
[Resolve]
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#Cache=no-negative
#DNSStubListener=yes
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
```

Comment: Looks like your DHCP server is specifying that DNS, so it is getting used as well as the netplan ones. Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001241/can-netplan-configured-nameservers-supersede-not-merge-with-the-dhcp-nameserve

Comment: I try adding : dhcp4-overrides:
  use-dns: false      , nothing change

Comment: Worth asking, but did you do sudo netplan apply and then re-check?

Comment: Of course I'm using "sudo" :)

Comment: I ran a test on ubuntu server 20.04. My dns was from DHCP at first. Adding nameservers option made it 2 dns servers from netplan and 1 from DHCP. Adding the override made it netplan only.  What is your /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/systemd/resolved.conf ?

Comment: @jtessier72 I add resolv.conf and resolved.conf on the main question

Comment: Try this... change 1.0.0.1 to 2.2.2.2 in netplan and use 'sudo netplan apply'. And check the dns servers. Or just set "DNS=1.1.1.1" in /etc/systemdresolved.conf. Seems like netplan is not applied or 192.168.1.1 is coming from somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered here https://askubuntu.com/a/1084736/993552

Basically in your /etc/netplan/filename.yaml add

```
dhcp4-overrides:
  use-dns: no
```

sudo netplan apply #do this after changing config

This will ensure whatever DNS nameservers come from DHCP will not be used by your link (ethernet or whatever network connection you change settings in)

Example

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens5:
        dhcp4: true
        dhcp4-overrides:
            use-dns: no
        dhcp6: false
        set-name: ens5
        nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4]
version: 2
```